# Why is Pulp Fiction's opening scene different to the one near the end?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, continuity, pulp-fiction, production-mistakes

In the opening scene of Pulp Fiction at the restaurant, right before the titles, Honeybunny says:

> Any of you fucking pricks move, I will execute every motherfucking last one of you!

But when the movie again reaches this scene at end of the movie (with Jules and Vincent in the restaurant) we hear Honeybunny saying the same dialogue but now it is:

> Any of you fucking pricks move, I will execute every one of you motherfuckers!

Why is there such a difference in two scenes? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It clearly *looks* like a continuity error, but if IMDb's [Pulp Fiction FAQ page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110912/faq#.2.1.9) is to be believed:

> **Why is what Yolanda says in the beginning different from what she says at the end?**
>
> Tarantino has explained that this is not an error, rather, he did this on purpose. When we first examine the scene, we are seeing Ringo and Yolanda's conversation from their perspective. Obviously, because this is their conversation, what we hear first is probably what was actually said. However, at the end of the film, what is said is different because we are no longer viewing the situation from Ringo and Yolanda's perspective, but rather everyone else in the diner, most specifically Jules.

So it is claimed that, in effect, this was done intentionally to further punctuate Pulp Fiction's disjointed, non-linear narrative with a [Rashomon-inspired](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashomon_effect) scene as presented from different perspectives (so it's simply *remembered* differently).

Comment: While this may well be true, if I ever made a multi-million $ movie and let a continuity error slip through, I'd totally try to pass it off as a "homage to Rashomon"

Comment: That's so awesome great answer I always wondered about that continuity error my ass Tarantino does everything for a reason.

Comment: The FAQ link's fragment id changed, so the link is now https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110912/faq#fq0000013

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it was on purpose. Another example of Quentin Tarantino still keeping this alive today is in The Hateful Eight when Major Marquis Warren is telling the story of Chester Charles Smithers. His lines are very intense compared to the flashback of Joe Gage poisoning the coffee whereas his lines are much calmer and almost casual. Joe Gage's point of view vs. Major Maquis's point of view.

Comment: "Yes it was on purpose" you should prove this claim.

Answer (score -7):

Tarantino didn't do the honey bunny dialogue wrongly on purpose cos nothing quentin puts in his films is ever by mistake?
Well he did Jules same ,"And i will strike down..." etc scene has different words later on in film .

And if tou visit Tarantino's movie , Reservoir Dogs ? 
And see all mistakes of running over and over again past the same shop windows cos of useless editing continuity and at same time you can see cameramen w cameras running along filming them running cos they are reflected in th windows. 
the end

Comment: So you're saying he got the dialogue wrong the second time round by accident?